# Android how to get original data from bluetooth hid device?

Tags: android, bluetooth, hid

I want to get the data from `hid BlueTooth device` (as a mouse), app  get this data directly. I have search many document, it seems I can't get the original data except the phone is rooted, I want to know if there is a good solution that I can use. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely there is no good solution for this case. Mouse and keyboard are used as input devices by Android itself.

Comment: yes, i think so ,but Hardware Engineer told me hid device send data to android system,Theoretically, it should be possible to get data  directly